# How can I use a simple Dropdown list in the search box of GridView::widget, Yii2?

Tags: php, search, gridview, drop-down-menu, yii2

I am trying to make a dropdown list in the search box of a `GridView::widget`, Yii2 for searching related data. So, how can I create a simple dropdown list in the search box of `GridView::widget`, Yii2 framework?

Thanks.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can also use below code

```
[
    'attribute'=>'attribute name',
    'filter'=>array("ID1"=>"Name1","ID2"=>"Name2"),
],
```

OR

```
[
    'attribute'=>'attribute name',
    'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Model::find()->asArray()->all(), 'ID', 'Name'),
],
```

Comment: How to change value as it was in array?

Comment: how to give placeholder in 1st  method in above given answer

Answer (score 78):

Add this in Gridview columns array:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'attribute_name',
    'value' => 'attribute_value',
    'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList($searchModel, 'attribute_name', ArrayHelper::map(ModelName::find()->asArray()->all(), 'ID', 'Name'),['class'=>'form-control','prompt' => 'Select Category']),
],
```

Change values according to your attributes.

Comment: Is there any way that I might be able to pass this filtered value to generate a pdf