# How to perform Filter using Multi Select Dropdown in Yii2 GridView

Tags: php, yii2, dropdown

Here i like to explain my problem clearly,

am trying to perform multi select dropdown filter, before this multiselect filter i have a basic filter.

Am using kartik-v dropdown extension

**search.php**

```
<?php
     $status = ArrayHelper::map(Status::find()->all(),'id','status');
     echo $form->field($model, 'status')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                            'data' => $status,
                            'language' => 'en',
                            'options' => [
                            'placeholder' => 'Select Status..',
                            'multiple' => true
                            ],
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'allowClear' => true
                            ],
                    ]);
?>
```

**claimsSearch.php**

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
            'status' => $this->status
        ]);
```

if i try the above code am getting error as below

```
Array to string conversion
```

but here i don't know how to write filter code.

update searchview:
[image: search view snapshot]

Comment: Where $this->status comes from?

Comment: see above in search.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to delete 'status' from EmployeeSearch rules.
You cannot filter such field automatic way.
Or you must set up custom filter value for status column, like this (you can dig into this direction):

[How can I use a simple Dropdown list in the search box of GridView::widget, Yii2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231013/how-can-i-use-a-simple-dropdown-list-in-the-search-box-of-gridviewwidget-yii2)  Try this link

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the model in that widget. You shoudl use like this:

```
echo $form->field($mySearchModel, 'state_10')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => $status,
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Select Status ...',
        'multiple' => true
    ],
]);
```

And your select it's probably returning an array. So, your search would be something like:

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'status' => ('in', 'status', $this->status)
]);
```

See more examples of queries [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where()-detail).

If that solution don't work, i will sugest you to do a `var_dump($yourModel->status)` in your view, just to check what is returning.

Comment: am getting error and same time its not showing any data in gridview(on index page)

Comment: Can you update your question with your search view and modelsearch?

Answer (score 0):

$this->status is array?

So, you can use

```
<?php
 $status = ArrayHelper::map(Status::::model()->findAllByAttributes(array("id"=>$status));(),'id','status');
 echo $form->field($model, 'status')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                            'data' => $status,
                            'language' => 'en',
                            'options' => [
                            'placeholder' => 'Select Status..',
                            'multiple' => true
                            ],
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'allowClear' => true
                            ],
                    ]);
?>
```