# GridView::Widget search data from another table

Tags: gridview, yii2, widget

I have a GridView::widget which is populated with this method:

`StabilimentiController.php`

```
public static function getGridColumns($isMine = true, $readonly = false) {
 $c = [
            'denominazione',
            [
                'attribute'      => 'provincia',
                'value'          => 'indirizzo.provincia',
                'headerOptions'  => ['class' => 'table-col-provincia'],
                'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'table-col-provincia'],
            ],
            [
                'attribute'      => 'created_by',
                'value'          => 'azienda.ragioneSociale',
                'headerOptions'  => ['class' => 'table-col-createdBy'],
                'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'table-col-createdBy'],
            ]
    ];

return $c;
}
```

I have some problems in creating a searchable inputBox for the field created_by.

`Created_by` in my model is defined as integer, it's a code to identify univocally the company (azienda).

In my `Stabilimenti.php` model I have this method to catch it and then with the .notation inside the getGridColumns method I can reach the ragioneSociale field that is the one I'm interested in.

```
/**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
*/
    public function getAzienda() {
        return $this->hasOne(Azienda::className(), ['id' => 'azienda_id'])->inverseOf('stabilimenti');
    }
```

The ouput is what I want, the only problem is that the searchable field in my GridView take as input the int code and not the `ragioneSociale` string, and is not very userFriendly.

In my `StabilimentiSearch.php`

```
public function rules(){
    return [
           [['id', 'azienda_id', 'created_by', 'updated_by'], 'integer'],
           [['denominazione', 'indirizzo', 'citta', 'localita', 'provincia', 'cap', 'produttore', 'utente', 'azienda' ], 'safe'],
             array('ragioneSociale', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        ];
```

I put `ragioneSociale` as safe and with the search option, but I've some difficulties in bind it correctly to the inputBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [#29231013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29231013). If you want drop down, try this:

```
            [
                'attribute'      => 'created_by',
                'value'          => 'azienda.ragioneSociale',
                'headerOptions'  => ['class' => 'table-col-createdBy'],
                'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'table-col-createdBy'],
                'filter'         => ArrayHelper::map(Azienda::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'ragioneSociale')
            ]
```

If you want inputBox and text search, see https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview. Add property and filter condition to search model:

```
class StabilimentiSearch extends Stabilimenti
{
    public $ragioneSociale;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // ... more stuff here
            [['ragioneSociale'], 'safe'],
            // ... more stuff here
        ];
    }

    public function search($params)
    {
        // create ActiveQuery
        $query = Tour::find();

        $query->joinWith(['azienda']);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        // No search? Then return data Provider
        if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }
        // Some filters
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            //... other searched attributes here
        ])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'azienda.ragioneSociale', $this->ragioneSociale]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

And use this property as attribute in GridView:

```
            [
                'attribute'      => 'ragioneSociale',
                'value'          => 'azienda.ragioneSociale',
                'headerOptions'  => ['class' => 'table-col-createdBy'],
                'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'table-col-createdBy'],
            ]
```